# How to change the jenkins `/tmp` dir location?

Tags: jenkins

How can I change the location where jenkins store temp data in its slaves. Currently, it shuts down the connection to my slaves because it complains about the following

```
Disk space is too low. Only 0.119GB left on /tmp.
```

I want to move the tmpdir location to something like `/var/tmp/` instead of `/tmp`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Java Service Wrapper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon).
And config your wrapper(look example)

```
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=../tmp
```

Or you can create symbolic link `/var/tmp` folder and put on home jenkins daemon.

Answer (score 28):

Just add "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmp" to the java command line options (you don't need any extra service wrapper).

Depending on your installation there might be an existing startup script and/or config file this can go into.  On my fedora system, I can add the option to the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file:

```
## Type:        string
## Default:     "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
## ServiceRestart: jenkins
#
# Options to pass to java when running Jenkins.
#
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp"
```

Comment: On Windows there is a jenkins.xml file in the installation dir to which you can add the command line option.

Comment: It doesn't seem to honour this. I put that in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins on CentOS7 but it keeps crashing out trying to execute files in /tmp still.

Answer (score 10):

On a debian/ubuntu machine, add the following to the file `/etc/default/jenkins`:

```
# use a different tmpdir for jenkins
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/"
```

Answer (score 7):

If using "SSH Slaves Plugin", you can set [JVM Options in "Advanced settings"](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURE.md#advanced-settings) and add:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/my/temp
```

Comment: If you set the option in the SSH slaves plugin, you don't need to add any command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows agent, assuming you have set it up as a Windows service wrapping a call to Java Web start, you should see a jenkins-slave.xml file in the agent's target folder.

You can edit this file and add `-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Whatever\folder\` in the `<arguments>` tag to configure the temporary folder.
E.g.

```
 <arguments>-Xrs -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Temp\ -jar "%BASE%\slave.jar" -jnlpUrl http://jenkins-master-whatever/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999</arguments>
```

You'll need to restart the service to see your modifications at work.

Answer (score 1):

Running on FreeBSD, you can configure the temp directory by adding this line to your `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
jenkins_java_opts="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

When jenkins is wrapped, e.g. bootstrapped as a windows service, add the configuration to the %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins.xml `<arguments>` element
or on a slave, %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins-slave.xml

Answer (score 1):

Same information as other answers but official support article from CloudBees regading JNA error on Jenkins Master (although the same applies for Jenkins Nodes):

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215281717-Jenkins-fails-to-start-with-JNA-error

To change the temporary directory that Jenkins uses, you need to:

- append `-Djava.io.tmpdir=$JENKINS_HOME/tmp` into `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable in either `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` or `/etc/default/jenkins` file depending on your OS
- create `/var/lib/jenkins/tmp` using the Unix user that runs the Jenkins process

Answer (score 1):

On modern Jenkins you can use UI option in the Jenkins Configuration which is called "Override temporary dir location"

[image]

Comment: Cannot find this on version 2.319.1.
What does "Jenkins Configuration" mean? Can you share the exact path you followed on the web interface to find this setting? Also please share specific version of Jenkins you found this setting on.

Answer (score 0):

On a slave you can just add it to the slaves advanced parameter in Jenkins -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/

Comment: "add it to the slaves advanced parameter in jenkins", this is not clear. Which specific setting are you referring to? How is it on the web interface? If so detail the exact path you followed to find it.

Comment: I believe the OP meant in the ssh agents configuration on the slave in the JVM_OPTIONS. i.e https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agents-plugin/blob/main/doc/CONFIGURE.md