# jenkins with slave nodes /tmp disk space too low

Tags: jenkins

I added a slave node to jenkins master server system. It tells me the /tmp directory size for that slave node is too low. Is there a possibility to increase the disk space for /tmp?

I get the error:

```
Disk space is too low. Only 0.511GB left on /tmp.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a separate /tmp partition.

First way - you can try just ssh to machine and clean up /tmp dir (if you have something important in /tmp - that is not good, because /tmp cleans up automatically on OS reboot, /var/tmp/ doesn't).

Second way - you can increase size of /tmp partition - to get a recipe you must know filesystem on your slave and partitioning schema. Ssh to your slave and do this `df -T`, it will show you this info, and available space in /tmp (which also good to know for the first way).

Comment: By default on most Linux systems, `/tmp` is an ephemeral directory that runs out of ram only. The answer should not be to add more ram. It's perfectly acceptable for many Jenkins slaves to run with 512MB ram like the original question's situation. Not sure what the answer should be as of yet, but this isn't the answer.

Comment: This is the proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675783/how-to-change-the-jenkins-tmp-dir-location