# Can't start Jenkins service on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have an Ubuntu server and have installed Jenkins for Continuous Integration on it. I tried to run some builds this morning and they would not run. I looked at the logs and realised that in /var/log/jenkins there were some large log files filling up my hard drive on the server. I deleted these files and attempted to restart Jenkins.

At this point Jenkins will now no longer start. I have had a look at my /tmp directory and it looks like there is some sort of memory leak which is creating a large 1MB file called winstonexxxxxxxxxxx.jar in my tmp directory which fills the entire 1mb space of my tmp directory.

Can anyone help with how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it wasn't a typo - can you elaborate on why you have limited the /tmp directory to 1MB?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue and has been [resolved as 2018-02-14](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22088).

Suggested solutions when working with an older Jenkins:

1. Make sure all Jenkins processes are closed and nothing is running at your Jenkins port (by default `8080`)
2. Start Jenkins
3. Should Jenkins still not start-up, then maybe the 1 MB of `/tmp` space is the problem. Either enlarge it, or use any of the following solutions to change the temporary directory for Jenkins: [How to change the jenkins `/tmp` dir location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675783/how-to-change-the-jenkins-tmp-dir-location)
4. Should the `tmp` directory still be filling up, you could install the [Tmp Cleaner Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tmp+Cleaner+Plugin).